# No puedo eliminar error 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pillow, typeerror

tengo un trabajo de esteganografía, el profesor nos dejó por hacer un código yo lo copio y pego de internet tal cual pero me aparece int object is not subscriptable

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
from PIL import Image
import math #Utilizado sólo para redondear hacia abajo

caracter_terminacion = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]


def obtener_representacion_ascii(caracter):
    return ord(caracter)

def obtener_representacion_binaria(numero):
    return bin(numero)[2:].zfill(8)

def cambiar_ultimo_bit(byte, nuevo_bit):
    return byte[:-1] + str(nuevo_bit)

def binario_a_decimal(binario):
    return int(binario, 2)

def modificar_color(color_original, bit):
    color_binario = obtener_representacion_binaria(color_original)
    color_modificado = cambiar_ultimo_bit(color_binario, bit)
    return binario_a_decimal(color_modificado)

def obtener_lista_de_bits(texto):
    lista = []
    for letra in texto:
        representacion_ascii = obtener_representacion_ascii(letra)
        representacion_binaria = obtener_representacion_binaria(representacion_ascii)
        for bit in representacion_binaria:
            lista.append(bit)
    for bit in caracter_terminacion:
        lista.append(bit)
    return lista

def ocultar_texto(mensaje, ruta_imagen_original, ruta_imagen_salida="salida.png"):
    print("Ocultando mensaje...".format(mensaje))
    imagen = Image.open(ruta_imagen_original)
    pixeles = imagen.load()

    tamaño = imagen.size
    anchura = tamaño[0]
    altura = tamaño[1]

    lista = obtener_lista_de_bits(mensaje)
    contador = 0
    longitud = len(lista)
    for x in range(anchura):
        for y in range(altura):
            if contador < longitud:
                pixel = pixeles[x, y]


                rojo = pixel[0]
                verde = pixel[1]
                azul = pixel[2]

                if contador < longitud:
                    rojo_modificado = modificar_color(rojo, lista[contador])
                    contador += 1
                else:
                    rojo_modificado = rojo

                if contador < longitud:
                    verde_modificado = modificar_color(verde, lista[contador])
                    contador += 1
                else:
                    verde_modificado = verde

                if contador < longitud:
                    azul_modificado = modificar_color(azul, lista[contador])
                    contador += 1
                else:
                    azul_modificado = azul

                pixeles[x, y] = (rojo_modificado, verde_modificado, azul_modificado)
            else:
                break
        else:
            continue
        break

    if contador >= longitud:
        print("Mensaje escrito correctamente")
    else:
        print("Advertencia: no se pudo escribir todo el mensaje, sobraron {} caracteres".format( math.floor((longitud - contador) / 8) ))

    imagen.save(ruta_imagen_salida)


ocultar_texto("Hola, mundo. Esto es un mensaje oculto desde parzibyte.me/blog", "oveja.png")
```

Agradezco la ayuda, no sé si se me está escapando algo o bien será un tema con la configuración de mi máquina.

Comment: No agregues "basura" a tu propia pregunta ya que no es información útil. En tu caso podrías agregar el texto del error tal cual aparece. Tanto el código como el texto del error siempre se deben agregar como texto con formato.

Comment: Tener que añadir spam es señal inequívoca de que falta explicar algo del problema. CUál será el problema? CUáles son los datos de entrada del problema? Cuál será la salida esperada? Todo eso va en vez del spam

Answer (score 0):

Para acceder a los valores RGB de cada píxel primero tienes que procesar la imagen correctamente.
Ello se hace con el método [`convert`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert).
Por tanto tienes que definir `rgb_imagen = imagen.convert('RGB')`.
Ahora puedes acceder a cada pixel `rojo, verde, azul = rgb_imagen.getpixel((x, y))`.